# Date is Subtracting 1 day after converting to other format

Tags: apex, datetime

For some reasons, the Date is subtracting **one day** whenever it is converted to other formats, I don't have any idea why this is happening. I am using `.addDays(1)` to temporarily solve the issue, but I don't think It is the right thing to do, there's got to be some solution or fix for this.

Below is the code I am using.

```
private static String formatDateToString(Date dateToFormat) 
    {   
        String dateString = null;
        if(dateToFormat != null) 
        {
            DateTime convertedDate = dateToFormat;
            dateString = convertedDate.format('MMMM dd, yyyy');
        }

        return dateString;
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`DateTime.format()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) ...

> Converts the date to the local time zone and returns the converted date as a formatted string using the locale of the context user

Since you're converting a `Date` value (not a `DateTime`), it's getting converted from midnight GMT. Presumably your context user is not in GMT, and this results in the date getting shifted one day to account for the time zone difference.

`Date` itself has a  [`format()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_methods_system_date) method, and I'd suggest you use that instead, as no time-zone correction is involved when working with pure `Date` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to convert a Date field to a DateTime in the correct (local) Time Zone:

```
DateTime.NewInstance(dateField.year(), dateField.month(), dateField.day());
```